# Adaptive Layout 3.5 inch iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode6, adaptive-ui, adaptive-layout

I'm really new to the adaptive layout scene. I'm working on a project that I want to look really great on all iPhone screen sizes.

The question I have is: Is it possible to place a text box in a specific spot on each screen? The specific situation is that I have an image that takes up a majority of the screen. And I want to place an input box on top of that. Here is a screenshot to give you an idea of what I'm talking about.

[image]

And here is a screenshot to kind of show you how I have the background image set up.

[image]

The background image is placed perfectly and looks good on all screen sizes.

Do I need to place the textbox specifically for each screen size using size classes?

Comment: auto-layout may help on you because that and its constraints are designed for serving specifically that purpose: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: How do I go about doing that for each size? If I set a top margin of 392 to get it in the right place on the 5.5" then it's way too low on the 3.5".

Comment: it depends on many details, because if the image is adjusted to the middle, you could create an relative distance from the center; but on the other end and in the worst case of scenario you can set up the `constant` properties programmatically after you detected the screen's size. it is too board to answer properly, there are not enough information – but those would be the ideas in general.

Comment: For this background image you want to keep 3 images ..1x n 2x n 3x in imageassests folder based on the scren size it will take automatically .. remember these 3 images are with same name.. n next you want to keep the text field as vertical center and horizontal center